# Get Member details using Java in Microsoft Bot Framework SDK

Tags: java, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am currently working on delivering 1:1 messages to the users in Teams.

Problem Statement: I am having trouble trying to get the member details to populate the Channel Account to set the ConverstationParameters object to create conversation if the user is not part of a team. Is there a way I could get the details of the user without having the user part of a Team. I wasn't able to find any reference documentation to how to get this information for Java.

Below is my code snippet:

1. Setup credentials and initialize a connection using Connector Client.
2. Populate Channel account with recipient details for set members on Conversation Parameters Object.

   ```
    Activity message = MessageFactory.text("Hello World");

    MicrosoftAppCredentials credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(appClientID, appClientSecret);

    try (ConnectorClient client = new RestConnectorClient(serviceUrl, credentials)) {

        logger.info("** Connector Client Set: {} **", client);

        ConversationParameters conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters();
        conversationParameters.setIsGroup(false); 

        CompletableFuture<ChannelAccount> user = ((Conversations) client.getConversations())
                .getConversationMember(recipient, teamsInternalId); // Don't want to use this because the user has to be part of the same team which is not true in our case. 

        logger.info("** Aysnc get User details call **");
        logger.info("** AAID: {} **", user.get().getAadObjectId());

        try {
            conversationParameters.setMembers(Collections.singletonList(user.get()));
        } catch (ErrorResponseException e) {
            logger.error("** User Error : {}**", e.getMessage());
        }


        conversationParameters.setTenantId(tenantId);
        TenantInfo tenantInfo = new TenantInfo(tenantId);

        TeamsChannelData channelData = new TeamsChannelData();
        channelData.setTenant(tenantInfo);
        conversationParameters.setChannelData(channelData);

        CompletableFuture<ConversationResourceResponse> conversationResourceResponse = new CompletableFuture<ConversationResourceResponse>();
        try {
            conversationResourceResponse = client.getConversations()
                    .createConversation(conversationParameters);
            logger.info("** Create Conversation: {} **", conversationResourceResponse.get().getId());
        } catch (ErrorResponseException e) {
            logger.error("** Create Conversation : {} **", e.getMessage());
        }

        CompletableFuture<ResourceResponse> response = client.getConversations()
                .sendToConversation(conversationResourceResponse.get().getId(), message);
        logger.info("** Send  Conversation **", response.get().getId());
   ```

Comment: Looking at the error seems like there is an issue with user id. The provided user ID does not exist in the tenant. Could you please check this again and confirm? Also please share the documentation sample you are referencing?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT : I am trying to follow this reference on the MSFT GitHub page : https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/blob/main/libraries/bot-connector/README.md . From this reference example: I don't have bot id because I am building the bot within my application which is connecting with the Bot Service Channel which connects to Teams.

Comment: Bot id is same as the App id, could you please confirm now if the issue is with the user id?

Comment: Perhaps the [Java MSGraph sample bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/java_springboot/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) might be of help? I'm still not clear on how you're architecting your application, but this might be a good starting point. The document you're referencing is somwhat old.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Yes I modified my code further and you will see the edit above. I was able to post to the recipient but the user must be part of the team. Currently, the scope in the manifest file for the bot installed in teams is set to "Team". Does changing that to "Personal" will help me to post to user directly instead of being part of a team ?

Comment: @AP01 Is it possible to get the user details without having the user to be part of a team ? Can I post a message to an user directly ?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT : I would like to know if there is a way for me get the details of the user directly without having to give teamInternalId to get details of the user ?

Comment: Microsoft Graph APIs (as linked in the sample) should allow you to get details about an individual user through the use of user auth. They must have messaged the bot and authenticated themselves before it will work though.

Comment: You can get user details using either id or userPrincipalName - [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Please check this to post the messages to the user - [Proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet). And you can use Graph API to proactively install your app for your users before sending messages.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on the teamInternalId to get details of the user? Do you mean user is not part of the team or you are not part of team?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT : I want to send messages to an user who is not part of the team. To do that I would need the userid(id) which is unique to the bot and user. I would like to get those details because there is no other option but to use userid to create a conversation.

Comment: @MAV The bot **must** authenticate the user and the user **must** grant permission *before* you can obtain information about them. It doesn't need to be in a Team chat specifically, it could be a 1:1 chat, but you still need to perform user auth. Once you authenticate a user with Microsoft Graph, you can use those APIs to get their User ID, Name, Email Address, Position, Team memberships, etc. Without user auth, the bot doesn't really know anything about the user, since by default Bot Framework bots are stateless.

Comment: @AP01: In my case, the user is not communicating with the bot but my bot is communicating with the user to send some notifications. It's a fire and forget and the user will not respond to those message. In that scenario, what is the best course of action for 1:1 ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your ask. Even if the bot will send proactive notifications without the user's input, the initial "setup" conversation still has to happen, since you do not want to simply message all members of a team, but rather wish to individually message users. The bot needs some way of knowing who those users are. It would be akin to me asking you to send a letter to someone, but you don't have their name or address.

Comment: @AP01 : I have their email address and providing the bot to deliver the messages to the user with such email address. My ask is how would I able to deliver these messages 1:1 without having the user be in the same team as the bot. I just want to send these messages freely without any pre-reqs. Does it make sense or do you want me to re-phrase ?

Comment: As the Bot Framework and the Azure resources are currently designed, there is **no mechanism** to achieve user-specific notifications without any pre-requisite steps. Due to the stateless nature of Bot Framework bots as well as the need to respect user privacy by not getting, storing, and using their info without their explicit permission, your user must initiate communication with the bot once before you may proactively message them. You can send blanket messages to all users without auth, but they *still* must initiate contact once.

Comment: @AP01 In the above example I posted which is working fine does not need the user to initiate the conversation. The Bot SDK is able to initialize a conversation with the user but in the same team and is able to deliver the message.

Comment: You specifically said *outside the team* in your question. Within the team, the bot already has access to APIs that allow it to obtain this information. Joining the team *is* the pre-requisite step. Outside the team, 1:1 communication is not possible without some prior steps.

Comment: @AP01 Appreciate your insight on this.. Thanks much !

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the above requirement following these steps:

1. Check if my app is installed for the user using Graph API.
2. If not installed, force install the app for the user using Graph API.
3. Then retrieve the conversation chat id.
4. Use this chat id to send the message to the user.

There steps are outline here on the MSFT reference page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=dotnet

I hope this answer helps anyone in the same boat who would like to send messages directly 1:1 from an app to a Teams user without any mutual Team condition.